Can you use RTK Query queryFn with transformResponse and createEntityAdapter?
I'm pretty new to using adapters and RTK Query, and also not too advanced with TS, so sorry if the answer seems obvious! Everything is working fine when using queryFn with firebase and using the response data through my app, but I'm trying to use createEntityAdapter and keep running into TS issues and the overall logic not working correctly.
Here's the API I'm creating to retrieve all of the previous workouts from firestore. I've tried just returning what I have in the transformResponse method inside of queryFn, but that throws an error since it's expecting the result formatted similar to {data: data}. I've read in other places you can't use queryFn and transformResponse together since transformResponse is used to transform the data received from the query method and queryFn allows you to do this. Assuming there's an obvious approach with queryFn but I'm not knowledgable enough to see it.
export const workoutApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery<WorkoutError>(),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getWorkouts: build.query<EntityState<Workout, string>, void>({
      queryFn: async () => {
        try {
          const workouts = await firestore().collection('workouts').get();
          const data = workouts.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            name: doc.data().name,
            date: format(doc.data().date.toDate(), 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
          }));

          return { data };
        } catch (e) {
          return {
            error: {
              status: 500,
              message: (e as Error).message,
            },
          };
        }
      },
      transformResponse(res: Workout[]) {
        return workoutsAdapter.setAll(initialState, res);
      },
    }),
  }),
});

I get 2 typescript errors:
The first is on the queryFn method:

Type '() => Promise<{ data: { id: string; name: any; date: string;
}[]; error?: undefined; } | { error: { status: number; message:
string; }; data?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type '(arg:
void, api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}, baseQuery: (arg: void) =>
MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unique symbol, WorkoutError, {}>>) =>
MaybePromise<...>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ data: { id: string; name: any;
date: string; }[]; error?: undefined; } | { error: { status: number;
message: string; }; data?: undefined; }>' is not assignable to type
'MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<EntityState<Workout, string>,
WorkoutError, {} | undefined>>'.


The second is on the transformResponse method:

Type '(res: Workout[]) => EntityState<Workout, string>' is not
assignable to type 'undefined'.


I might just be doing this completely wrong, but all of the examples I've found use the standard query method instead of queryFn.
Any help is really appreciated! Maybe it's just not possible using queryFn, but at this point I'm lost.


I've read in other places you can't use queryFn and
transformResponse together since transformResponse is used to
transform the data received from the query method and queryFn
allows you to do this.

This is correct. If you check the transformResponse documentation the first thing it states is:

(optional, not applicable with queryFn)

Trying to use transformResponse is not intended to work when using the queryFn.
I think you are attempting to merge two completely separate concepts, i.e. RTK-Query caching query results vs Entity Adapters data structures for CRUD operations. The queryFn and its return value is simply used to return a value to the query cache. If you are also needing to update an entity adapter with the result value then I suspect that using onQueryStarted is what you are looking for. It's effectively an API endpoint "side-effect", e.g. when the query resolves you can issue side-effects to dispatch additional actions, or in your case update an entity adapter.
Example:
export const workoutApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery<WorkoutError>(),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    // Update endpoint return type to match what you are returning.
    // Here I'm assuming it is an array of Workout objects.
    getWorkouts: build.query<Workout[], void>({
      queryFn: async () => {
        try {
          const workouts = await firestore().collection('workouts').get();
          const data = workouts.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            name: doc.data().name,
            date: format(doc.data().date.toDate(), 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
          }));

          return { data };
        } catch (e) {
          return {
            error: {
              status: 500,
              message: (e as Error).message,
            },
          };
        }
      },
      onQueryStarted: async (arg, { queryFulfilled }) => {
        try {
          // data is Workout[] from queryFn
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
          workoutsAdapter.setAll(initialState, data);
        } catch(e) {
          // catch and handle/ignore error
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});

Since you can't use queryFn and transformResponse together another suggestion might be to directly return the transformed entity data from the query function, i.e. something like return { data: workoutsAdapter.setAll(initialState, data) };.
export const workoutApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery<WorkoutError>(),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getWorkouts: build.query<Workout[], void>({
      queryFn: async () => {
        try {
          const workouts = await firestore().collection('workouts').get();
          const data = workouts.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            name: doc.data().name,
            date: format(doc.data().date.toDate(), 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
          }));

          return {
            data: workoutsAdapter.setAll(initialState, data)
          };
        } catch (e) {
          return {
            error: {
              status: 500,
              message: (e as Error).message,
            },
          };
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});


Thanks so much for the elaborate response! Based on the RTK Query Advanced Concept docs, it seems that they recommend doing this (but using query and transformResponse) for large datasets making it easier for lookups and updates. I think your approach caches the normalized data where this would store the array in cache and then update the adapter separately, correct? I was looking for the former (if there's any actually difference), but I could still just be reading this wrong. Would appreciate your insight on this.

@AllanKiezel I've never used entity adapters, but seeing as how createEntityAdapter is part of the regular Redux-Toolkit library and not part of the RTK-Query module kind of leads me to understand them as separate mechanisms. Adapters are used to initiate the state of a state slice, update the states in case reducers, and create state selectors specific to the entities you are operating over. RTKQ is an abstraction built over top of state slices, with its own API.

@AllanKiezel You might be able to "merge" the two, but IMHO that unnecessarily complicates each separate concern. Use RTKQ to query data and cache the raw (or transformed) responses, use a separate state slice and entity adapter to apply your CRUD operations on that dataset the UI consumes.

What you’re saying makes a ton of sense and I’m starting to see the bigger picture. I think from this section in the docs it seems like they are meant to work together as you can return the adapter call from transform response. I just can’t seem to figure out how to do it with queryFn. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#transforming-responses

@AllanKiezel Hmm, thanks for sharing that, that's new to me. In this case then since you can't use queryFn and transformResponse together maybe try returning the transformed entity data from the query function, i.e. something like return { data: workoutsAdapter.setAll(initialState, data) };. I have no idea if RTKQ can handle the "response data" in this format though.

That actually worked! Copilot recommended it the other day, but then it went wild a things were made more complicated. :) Your solution worked and assuming that’s what transformResponse is doing under the hood (wild guess though). Appreciate it man!
